# Implementing Depth Limited Path Finding with Stack

Tags: python, search, depth-first-search

Hey like the title says I'm trying to implement a Depth limited search in Python3 that returns a path given a graph, start vertex and goal vertex. I'm struggling a bit with how to enforce the limit for a search. So far I have:

```
def dfs(g, v, goal, limit=-1):

    SENTINEL = object()    
    visitedStack = [v]
    path = ""

    while visitedStack:
        currentVertex = visitedStack.pop()    

        if g.getVertex(currentVertex) != None:
            if g.getVertex(currentVertex).visited == False:
                path += currentVertex + ' -> '

                g.getVertex(currentVertex).hasBeenVisited()

                if currentVertex == goal: 
                    return path[:-3]

                elif currentVertex == SENTINEL:
                    limit += 1

                elif limit != 0:
                    limit -= 1
                    visitedStack.append(SENTINEL)
                    visitedStack.extend(g.getVertex(currentVertex).getConnections()) 

     return "Depth limit was reached"
```

EDIT: I changed some of the code to check for visited vertices. After my edit the search getting returned doesn't work properly sometimes. For example, I'll set the depth limit to 3, but have a path of 4 or 5 getting returned. Other times I'll set the limit to 7 and have "limit reached" returned. NOTE: the smallest path is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the search goes to a deeper level, push a sentinel onto the stack and decrement the limit.  When you pop a sentinel off the stack increment the level.

```
def dfs_limit(g, start, goal, limit=-1):
    '''
    Perform depth first search of graph g.
    if limit >= 0, that is the maximum depth of the search.
    '''
    SENTINEL = object()
    visitedStack = [start]
    path = []

    while visitedStack:
        currentVertex = visitedStack.pop()

        if currentVertex == goal: 
            path.append(currentVertex)
            return ' -> '.join(path)

        elif currentVertex == SENTINEL:
            #finished this level; go back up one level
            limit += 1
            path.pop()

        elif limit != 0:
            # go one level deeper, push sentinel
            limit -= 1
            path.append(currentVertex)
            visitedStack.append(SENTINEL)
            visitedStack.extend(g.getVertex(currentVertex).getConnections())
```

If there are loops or multiple routes through the graph, you need to also keep track of which nodes have been visited so you don't duplicate work or get in an endless loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm getting a few issues though, I made some edits noted in my post

Comment: You add every unvisited node to the path, but never remove nodes.  The current node should be added to the end of the path when the search goes a layer deeper, but gets removed when the search comes back up a layer.  I revised my solution to keep track of the path.